# How do you open a command line?

Tags: command-line

How do you access the command line or run option to put the commands into the system?

Answer (score 26):

It is called **terminal**.

[image]

You can launch your terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or search from dash by pressing <kbd>Meta</kbd>/<kbd>Super</kbd>/<kbd>Windows</kbd> button and type terminal.

If you're using Gnome, Terminal is probably under Accessories in your Application menu, or you can also try <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up a launcher widget into which you can type "t-e-r-m-i..." to see all the terminal options.

[image]

**[Basic command line](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/basic-commands/C/more-info.html)**.

Enjoy your command line !

Comment: Worth adding that Terminal is probably under Accessories in your Application menu (it is for me anyhow, but I gave Unity the boot. Maybe Unity doesn't have an Application menu). You can also try <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>f2</kbd> for a launcher widget where you can start to type "t-e-r-m-i..." and get a list of terminal applications available to you.

Comment: Since I'm not using gnome now, I cannot update my answer. If you have gnome, feel free to edit my answer by adding screenshot for both gnome and gnome classic.

Comment: How do I mark an response as a good anaser?

Answer (score 11):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> on the keyboard. If you prefer, there should be something called Terminal in your programs menu. You can search for it by pressing "Windows" key and typing "terminal". Remember, commands in Linux are case sensitive (so upper- or lower-case letters matter).

Answer (score 1):

Command line can be accessed in couple of ways.

One is by using [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) . The default terminal emulator for Ubuntu ( with default Unity interface ) is [gnome-terminal](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/). It can be accessed by either pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> or by pressing the Ubuntu icon on the launcher and typing in the word "Terminal" or "gnome-terminal"

[image]

As you can see in the image, I've multiple terminal apps available, and indeed one [can install more than one](https://askubuntu.com/q/7605/295286) terminal emulator.

Another way to access command line is through the virtual console, called TTY. There are 6 virtual consoles available. Number of each console corresponds to the number of <kbd>Fx</kbd> key, where x is the number. For instance, to access TTY1, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> . To return to graphical environment , press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>, or repeatedly press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Arrow Left/Right</kbd> until you exit.

There are other, rather [hackish ways to access command line](https://askubuntu.com/q/636691/295286) , but for the 99% of the day-to-day tasks terminal emulator and tty are sufficient.

*Note* , when it comes to command-line, [terminology may get confusing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/85039).

Answer (score -2):

There are some great terminal programs like yakuake and guake that will put a drop-down terminal on your screen whenever you hit f12. I find them a little more elegant than opening a new terminal each time if you do a lot of command-line work.