# How to get to terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, prompt

I am a novice, using Ubuntu 14,04.  I have tried to install Skype, and it does not work.  I need it installed, but I read all the suggestions, and they all refer to using some `sudo` commands in  what I believe is a DOS-like command prompt menu - and I cannot find anywhere to access that?

I am sure this is a trivial question thousands have asked before, so a simple direction to where this is explained would suffice for me as help.

I also realize that I need to know  what "distribution" my Ubuntu is, and if is 32 or 64 bit - where do I find that information?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: May be we can just help you with Skype. Can you edit the question, and explain what's wrong with it, and how you've tried installing it.

Comment: The only option I appear to have is to use the download from skype.com, as there is no recognition by the Software Center of Skype.  So, I did that.  I actually downloaded several versions, as I did not know which version/distribution I am having.

Comment: I think I got the problem solved.  Thank you for your interest in helping me!  It did the trick to use the command-prompt instructions, and I got help to get that started.

Comment: This question is semi-related http://askubuntu.com/q/636691/295286

Answer (score 3):

To open the DOS-like terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> all together on your keyboard to open the terminal.

From the terminal prompt to find out what your distribution is, type in the following:

```
cat /etc/*release
```

it will produce text looking like this:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

To find out if it is 32bit or 64bit, type in:

```
getconf LONG_BIT
```

Example:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ getconf LONG_BIT
64
```

Then to install Skype, type in the following:

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

When `sudo` is used in front of the command, it is running at an elevated permission level, so it will ask for your password to continue to install the application.

To add a `Desktop` icon of `skype`, type in the following to copy one to your desktop, then make it executable.

```
cp /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop ~/Desktop/
chmod +x ~/Desktop/skype.desktop
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very impressive!  It was exactly what I needed.  It helped a lot.  But I face one small complication from it: although the machine confirmed the installation of Skype, I can't find it anywhere in the program overview, and I cannot find out how to open that program.  Again, I am sure there is a simply answer...

Comment: @MogensEliasen What complication are you still facing?

Comment: I cannot find out how to open that program.  There is no link to it, and it appears to be not recognized by the Software Center...

Comment: @MogensEliasen You can press the Windows Key (Super Key) on your keyboard, and type in Skype, and you should see an icon for it.  Or you can type in `skype &` at the Terminal prompt and it should launch it too.  Normally apps like that end up in the Internet group of applications.

Comment: OK - that appeared to work well.  Thank you!  Do I need to do this every time, or can I create a shortcut to my desktop?

Comment: @MogensEliasen I edited my answer to help you copy the skype launcher to the desktop, then make it so you can launch it from there.

Comment: @MogensEliasen Also, if I was able to help you, make sure you click the check-mark next to my answer.